# Array Adapter's "getView()" doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, adapter, loader

I'm unable to figure out, why the 'getView' method, in the BookAdapter class, never gets called. It seems like I'm stuck in a loop or something and debugging can't help me ._.

Here are my relevant classes:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Book>>
String log = MainActivity.class.getName();
String googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=10";
BookAdapter mBookAdapter;
ListView mBookListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_results);
    LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
    loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this);
    mBookAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Book>());
    mBookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_results);
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Book>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new BooksLoader(this, googleAPI);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Book>> loader, List<Book> books) {
    if(!mBookAdapter.isEmpty()) {
        mBookAdapter.clear();
        Log.i(log, "!!Load finished and adapter cleared");
    }

    updateUI(books);
    Log.i("MainActivity.java", "UI updated!");
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Book>> loader) {
    mBookAdapter.clear();
}

public void updateUI(List<Book> books){
    if(books != null && !books.isEmpty()) {
        mBookAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, books);
        mBookListView.setAdapter(mBookAdapter);
        Log.i(log, "Everything fine");
    }
}
```

BooksLoader.java

```
public class BooksLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader{


String mURL;

BooksLoader(Context context, String url){
    super(context);
    mURL = url;
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    forceLoad();
}

@Override
public List<Book> loadInBackground() {
    QueryUtils qu = new QueryUtils();
    String APIreturn = qu.makeHttpRequest(mURL);
    List<Book> books = qu.parseBooksFromJSON(APIreturn);
    return books;

   }
}
```

And the BooksAdapter.java

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

public BookAdapter(Context context, List<Book> books) {
    super(context, 0, books);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_result, parent, false);
    }


    Book currentBook = getItem(position);
    Log.i("BookAdapter.java", "Adapter loaded");


    TextView bookName = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.bookName);
    bookName.setText(String.valueOf(currentBook.getmBookName()));

    //TextViews für den Place vorbereiten und setzen.
    TextView bookDescription = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.bookDescription);
    bookDescription.setText(currentBook.getmBookDescription());


    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
    // so that it can be shown in the ListView
    return listItemView;

}}
```

Whenever i run it, it seems to get stuck after the "onLoadFinished()" method, in the mainActivity class. Everything till that point works fine. Parsing from JSON works flawless, the returned List looks good too, and the updateUI Method runs without failure.

If anyone is willing to dig through my code and point out, what I did wrong, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: So are you sure books are not null and not empty? :) is Log.i(log, "Everything fine"); actually called?

Comment: have you override function getCount()?

Comment: MainActivity extends or implement what?

Comment: thanks for your reply :)

Yep, "Everything fine" shows up in the logcat and at this line "mBookAdapter = new BookAdapter(this, books);" 

books has the size of 10

Comment: No, i did not overwrite the getCount() function and @Xenolion I'm afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: So what does adapter.getCount return? If it returns 0, or you have not overwriten this method, the getview will not get called, so theres your issue

Comment: Show where you the line of your Activity starts because its not there for example `public MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implement Something {`

Comment: Don't worry about `getCount()`. The `List` is being passed to the `super` constructor, so `ArrayAdapter` will handle the count correctly. Are you sure the `ListView` is visible in your layout?

Comment: @tjugg It does return 10

Comment: @Xenolion, I'm sorry, I thought I've already posted that. I added it to the main post.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh holy god... Still had  
    android:visibility="gone"  
    in the ListView, cause I copy&pasted it from a previous project... I feel so dumb right now ._. 
Guess I learned a valuable lesson today... Thanks for pointing that out and thanks to everyone that posted here

Comment: Hope you are good now!